M-TIP 27 Test 01 - Scenerio 01 - In second gen AC the terminal request an AAC
I'm working on the M-TIP - EMVCo L3 certification and on Test case 27 01 01
I keep receiving an error on the second generation of AC, the terminal keeps requesting the TC instead of AAC when the issuer responded with response 85,
I just need to know if there's any solution I can do on the ATM to fix this issue.
The ATM is Hitachi WIN10
If there is a log you need I can send it.
enter image description here

There is far too little detail regarding your project. There are no logs, no code, nothing really. You have not provided details regarding version of the test suite you are running, have not showed host logs, said nothing about the ATM application and device handler. ATM environment is quite specific and decision regarding second cryptogram type may be either in the local application or on the host.
Please add some detail and maybe it will be easier to provide answer applicable to your situation rather than a generic one.

I think you need to look at the value tag 8A in the second GENERATE AC command. It may be helpful to post the expectations of the test case. The issue may be inconsistent values for the issuer response code. In the ISO-8583 message you have field 39 that contains the issuer response code. There may also be a authorization response code embedded in the Issuer Authentication Data (tag 91) that is returned in field 55. The test case may test how the system handles an inconsistency between these values.
